# Online Playground does not appear in Safari

Tags: plutus-playground, macos

Using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and Safari v 15.2 (15612.3.6.1.8). The Playground URL (https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io) generates a blank page. It loads fine on Chrome and Brave (haven't actually run anything yet). Is this known? Is this fixable? I primarily use Brave, but it's worth fixing this issue if it is fixable.

Related: I tried tagging this with {playground safari macos catalina blank} Only "macOS" was accepted, as I do not have 150 reputation points (ie. could not post until I *removed* those very useful tags). This seems shortsighted, as the newbies who are facing challenges are more likely to generate tags that newbies who are facing challenges might find helpful. If someone is experienced enough to have 150 reputation points, s/he is less likely to be having newbie problems, and less likely to create tags that will help newbies. Is this an IOHK limitation, or a stackexchange limitation?

Comment: fwiw, confirming same results in Safari using macOs 12.1 Monterey. Reported errors: [Error] Viewport argument key "minimal-ui" not recognized and ignored. (playground.plutus.iohkdev.io, line 1)
[Error] SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name (anonymous function) (vendors.fe7bf06144dfb083c610.js:2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help confirm this bug as I am on macOS >10.15 (and I don't see the same problem) but I'd recommend raising a new Issue [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues).

That seems like the appropriate place to report this issue based on [this](https://testnets.cardano.org/en/programming-languages/plutus/resources/):

> User feedback is important because it helps us improve the Plutus Playground. We want to hear from you about any usability issues or bugs that you encounter, or any suggestions for improvement you may have.
> If you would like to provide your feedback, please raise an issue in the Plutus GitHub repository. Use the issue template provided and include the requested information as it helps our team understand what went wrong, or what we could do better.